# How to prove that a recursively defined contraction mapping on a sequence is convergent

Tags: cauchy-sequences, recursive-algorithms, complete-spaces

I'm asked to prove the following statement:

Let $f$ be a contraction mapping on a complete metric space $M$ in the sense that
$$
d(f(x), f(y)) \leq c d(x, y), \quad \forall x, y \in M
$$
for some $c \in(0,1) .$ Let $x_{1} \in M,$ and define $x_{n+1}=f\left(x_{n}\right)$ for $n=1,2, \ldots$ Prove that $x_{n}$ is convergent and its limit is the unique solution to the equation $f(x)=x$

I think I should use the Cauchy sequence to prove it. I'm trying something like $\forall m,n>N, d(x_m,x_n) \leq cd(x_{m-1},x_{n-1}) \leq \dots \leq c^{m-1}d(x_1,x_{m-n})$, but I'm not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: This is the usual Contraction Mapping Theorem with the usual proof. It is very easy to find a proof in text books or on the net. For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. Our professor introduced it when we are learning complete metric space so I'm not aware that it is a theorem. Now I can understand it. Thank you so much!